# $(ab)^p =(a^p)(b^p)$ for any two elements a,b in finite group G implies Sylow p-subgroup is unique

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite group such that  $p\ |\ o(G)$ and for any two elements $a,b\in G$, $(ab)^p =a^p b^p$. Let $P$ be Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Prove that there is a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $P \cap N= \{e\}$ and $PN=G$.

I think this assumption would lead us to the fact that  Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is unique. Once this is done, the rest trivially follows if we consider $N=G/P$. I'm stuck while doing that part. Am I in the correct direction?

Comment: What you write does not make much sense. $G/P$ is not even a subgroup of $G$. The uniqueness of $P$ does not immediately imply the existence of $N$, so no I don't think you are in the correct direction.

Comment: @DerekHolt if Sylow p-subgroup P is unique, then P is normal subgroup of G. Hence G/P does make sence.

Comment: I did not sat that $G/P$ did not make sense, I said that $G/P$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt ohkay! I mean if we construct a surjective homomorphism from G to P then kernel of that map must satisfy the properties of N

Comment: So $\alpha:G \to G$ with $\alpha(g)=g^p$ is a homomorphism. Let $p^i$ be the exponent of $P$. Then $P := \ker(\alpha^i)$ is normal in $G$ and you can take $N := {\rm im}(\alpha^i)$.